# Mongoose: Save a nested JSON with different Schemas

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

everyone. I want to save JSON documents with many levels, for example, I have a nested JSON with  levels of elements like this:

```
{   
 "created":"2015-11-10 15:47:41.107Z",
 "id_user" : "01",
 "version" : "1"
 "record" : {
    "name" : "Carl Powers",
    "reference" : [{ "url" : "www.test.com", "created" : "2015-11-10 15:47:41.107Z"}] 
 }
}
```

I want to save this JSON, using different Schemas for each element, because I want different collections in my MongoDB, I don't want a schema with embedded elements.

```
var ElementSchema = new Schema({
 created : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 id_user : String,
 version : { type: Number, min: 0 },
 record : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'recordSchema'}
});

var recordSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    reference : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'referenceSchema'}]
});

var referenceSchema = new Schema({
    url : String,
    created : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  });
```

Is possible to save my example JSON, entirely, in one go, using mongoose. Is necessary to put the ids of each element? In that case, what is the best way to generate each id and how to put in each element, once the JSON is received?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using sub-documents, here's an example:

```
var referenceSchema= new Schema({
    url : String,
    created : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var recordSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    reference : { type: [referenceSchema]}
});

var ElementSchema = new Schema({
 created : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 id_user : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
 version : { type: Number, min: 0 },
 record : { type: recordSchema }
});
```

To save the Element document with sub-documents:

```
var element = new ElementSchema({
   created: 'date',
   id_user: 'user-id',
   version: 2
   record: {
      name: 'name',
      reference: [{
         url: 'url1',
         created: 'date1'
      }, {
         url: 'url2',
         created: 'date2'
      }]
   }
});
```

[Here's the documentation for more queries for sub-documents:](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)